# what is wrong with this java script code

Tags: javascript

The below code is not adding a field in my html. If I remove newText section it works fine.

```
function add(){
    alert("hi");
    var addDiv = document.getElementById('addMoreUl');

    var ul=document.createElement('ul');

    var li=document.createElement('li');

    var newText = document.createElement('input');
    newText.setAttribute("name", Name);
    newText.setAttribute("type ", text);
    newText.setAttribute("value ", Value); 
    newText.setAttribute("id",box); 
    li.appendChild(newText);

    var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
    newSpan.innerText ="Reward Amount:";
    li.appendChild(newSpan);

    ul.appendChild(li);
    addDiv.appendChild(ul);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We can't guess what you're talking about when you say it "doesn't work". You need to be more specific. What is the intended behaviour and what does it actually do instead? Does it produce any errors on the console?

Comment: just a wild guess, try to use strings for your 2nd parameter when you call the `setAttribute()` method

Comment: It works fine in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AmkCn/3/ .

Comment: i am trying to add dynamic ul with javascript in my html page.but it not getting addeed but when i remove newText block in above code,work fine and add it

Comment: not working for me in crome

Comment: @user3333813 i have created the fiddle for you and it works fine just check it the only changes i made are i converter `newText.setAttribute("type ", text);` -->  `newText.setAttribute("type", 'some name');`

Comment: this is wired,not working in my code.

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
    newText.setAttribute("name", Name);
    \\newText.setAttribute("type ", text); \\space is there in "type "
    \\newText.setAttribute("value ", Value);  \\ space is there in "value "
    newText.setAttribute("type", text);
    newText.setAttribute("value", Value); 
    newText.setAttribute("id",box);
```

The problem is `newText.setAttribute("type ", text);` the space you have given after the `"type "` just remove it and try as `"type"` like `newText.setAttribute("type", text);`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmkCn/7/)

Comment: @user3333813 Just make it as answered.

Comment: please one more help,on add more i have to add fields,how can i dynamically delete them.i am how will i retrive id of dynamically added elements

Comment: @user3333813 on what event like(input onchange or onblur..etc) you want to delete your dynamically created elements.

Comment: i have a jsp page ,which display a form with 4 fields.and a add more button.when i click on add more another form should come,as many time click on add more that number of forms should come.. and each new create form should have a delete button ,and click on that should delete that form

Comment: @user3333813 do your form have dynamically generated ID's (i.e.) The four fields wrapped inside a container and unique ID for that container.

Comment: how do i get dynamic ids that i my issue

Comment: @user3333813 just count the number of clicks  globally using a variable for the add button and assign your id like `"form"+cickCount`

Comment: what u mean globally ? because i can swich b/w pages while doing add on this page..

Comment: how to keep those dynamic generated fields after reload the page

Answer (score 0):

something wrong with your code. if you check the browser console, you will see errors.

```
newText.setAttribute("name", Name); // where is Name from? a variable?
newText.setAttribute("type ", text); // should be "type" rather than "type ", I guess text should be 'text' here.
newText.setAttribute("value ", Value); // should be "value" rather than "value ".
newText.setAttribute("id",box); // is box a variable?
```